# Reducing/Simplifying time-series data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, postgresql, graph-theory

I have time-series data I'm looking to simplify (Reduce the number of points while having the graph maintain the same shape). For example if I had this data set:

```
Time: 1, Value: 5
Time: 6, Value: 5
Time: 11, Value: 5.1
Time: 12, Value: 5
Time: 20, Value: 5.2
Time: 22, Value: 6
Time: 23, Value: 10
```

The simplified version with a tolerance of .5 would be something like:

```
Time: 1, Value: 5
Time: 20, Value: 5.2
Time: 22, Value: 6
Time: 23, Value: 10
```

I'm aware of the Douglas–Peucker algorithm for GIS data but I'm not sure how to apply it to time-series data as the axises have different units. It would be awesome if I could do this all in the database.

Comment: That's not really the same shape, is it? For example, if it was a square wave `1,0 2,0 3,0 4,0 5,0 6,10` and you change it to `1,0 6,10` you're going to make a slope; you need to keep both endpoints along a constant slope.

Comment: @Phrogz That's true but if you had 1,0 5,0 6,10 it would be the same shape. Ideally there would be a bit of tolerance which is why I filtered out 3, 5.1 in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know of a built-in function for that. This query might do the job:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT t, val
          ,@(lead(val) OVER w - val) AS delta1
          ,@(lag(val)  OVER w - val) AS delta2
    FROM   tbl
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY t)
    ORDER  BY t
    )
SELECT t, val
FROM   x
WHERE  delta1 > 0.2
   OR  delta2 > 0.2
   OR  delta1 IS NULL
   OR  delta2 IS NULL;
```

I use the [window functions `lead()` and `lag()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) and the [absolute value operator `@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html) in a CTE to compute the deltas (should be fastest).

Only those rows are kept where at least one of the deltas is bigger than `0.2` (arbitrary threshold matching your example).

First and last row are special cases where the `delta1` or `delta2` are `NULL` (no leading / lagging row). We want to include those rows in any case, so I add NULL-checks to the final `SELECT`.

Produces the result you requested.

---

Another variant that concentrates on how much the direction changes:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT t, val
          ,@(lead(val) OVER w + lag(val) OVER w - 2*val) AS deviate
    FROM   tbl
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY t)
    ORDER  BY t
    )
SELECT t, val, deviate
FROM   x
WHERE  deviate > 0.2
   OR  deviate IS NULL;
```

This should preserve the shape more closely. This example keeps the row `Time: 12, Value: 5` and avoids the effect you describe in the comment. (Your example in the question did not point in this direction.)

Comment: That's so close to what I need. The only problem is if I had a tolerance of .5 it would return 1,5 20,6 23,10 which would change the shape of the graph...To keep the shape it should return 1,5 20,5.2 22,6, 23,10. Visually the difference between these if you were to graph is the first method would have a steady upwards trend towards the second point, in the second method the line would be relatively flat then suddenly jump up for the third point which is closer to the raw data.

Comment: @Mike: Your example seemed to focus on absolute values. I added a variant with focus on the change of direction.

Answer (score 1):

Ramer Douglas Peucker would work here - the units should be an issue.